# Параметры в функциях с кложерами

Tags: функции, swift, замыкания

Можно ли передать название параметра функции в функции примерно такого типа или близкое к нему?

```
func func(a: [Int], b: ((c: (Int), e: (Int)) -> Bool) -> [Int] {
 ///
}
```

Получается только такого вида:

```
func func(a: [Int], b: (Int, Int) -> Bool) -> [Int] {
 ///
}
```

Comment: Вот так? func example(a: [Int], b: (_ c: Int, _ e: Int) -> Bool) -> [Int] {///}

Comment: @OlegSoloviev не работает

Comment: Приведите пример, что вы хотите сделать, что-нибудь придумаем.